# How can I run same exe file consecutively N times?

Tags: batch-file, exe

I have an exe file. I want to run it several times repeatedly one after another. I tried below batch file but couldnt do it is there a way to do it? Sorry but  i am a rookie in code writing

```
@echo off  
start ran.exe
start ran.exe
start ran.exe
```

Comment: What do you mean "couldn't do it"?  This will run your program three times in three separate Windows.  If you want to run them consecutively instead of concurrently, then remove `start`.  If there's something else you don't understand, please explain yourself more clearly.

Comment: sorry. It works perfectly well as you said. It runs concurently in 3 times. I want to run it  than wait for it to stop, than run it again and wait it for stop , goes on N times .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `ran.exe` is in the current folder or on your path, then you simply write:

```
@echo off  
ran
ran
ran
```

to invoke it three times. If it is not found on the `PATH`, then use a fully qualified name like this:

```
@echo off  
c:\path\to\ran
c:\path\to\ran
c:\path\to\ran
```

Running a program is the normal effect of naming it on a line of a batch file.

Furthermore, because `.EXE` is listed in the `PATHEXT` environment variable, you don't need to include that in the name, unless there is also a file name `ran.com` since `.COM` is listed in the default value of `PATHEXT` ahead of `.EXE`.

The `START` builtin command is only needed in batch files for handling some special cases. See the output of `START /?1` for its documentation. In general, you don't need it just to launch programs.

**Update:** To generalize this to N invocations, use the `FOR` command. `FOR` is extremely powerful, type `FOR /?` at the command prompt for documentation. For N repeats specified as the argument to the batch file, and passing the current count to the command as its first argument do this:

```
@echo off  
for /L %%N in (1,1,%1) do c:\path\to\ran %%N
```

The tricky thing to remember with `FOR` is that the iteration variable must be named with two percent signs in batch files. The help text says that, but only in passing.

**Update 2:** Some more details and explanation.

In this case, we want to repeat a command N times. `FOR` supports a variety of kinds of loops, but the easiest way to get exactly N iterations is to use its `/L` option which uses a starting value, a step size, and an ending value to define the number of iterations.
These are specified in parenthesis, as `FOR /L %%N (start,step,end)`. To get a simple counter of 1 to N, we tell it to start at 1, step by 1, and to stop at the value of the first argument to the batch file which is named `%1`.

The arguments to the batch file itself are named as `%1` through `%9`, and `%*` names all of the arguments. Note that there is a vast minefield of subtlety here related to properly quoting file names that contain spaces. To keep life simple, try very hard not to need to do that. Otherwise, `CALL /?` documents the command line argument conventions, and `SET /?` documents many things related to general batch file variables.

Other forms of `FOR` let you iterate over files (no option), directories (`/D`), directories recursively in a tree (`/R`), or various parts of the contents of files (`/F`).

Comment: How can I run it consecutively with N times?

Comment: can you explain what does  /L and (1,1,%1) mean?

Comment: Ok I understand what does L do but what about (1,1,%1)?

Comment: See further update. (start,step,end). Count from 5 to 1 by writing (5,-1,1). I used an argument of the batch for for the end condition.

Comment: thank you very much for your reply. It is very helpful. Nevertheless, I could not achieve to work it properly. I guess I make a mistake but cannot see it. Anyway, thanks a lot